# Video Filters like Instagram and save in SDCARD

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing

Color Channel Mixer (Info.)
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorchannelmixer

I am trying to creating video filters using FFMpeg and OpenCV just like Instagram Video filters.
So if I want to create Sepia Effect Then I have to use color channel mixer for that with RGBA values
ex. colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131 (This code for Sepia Effect)
Now I want to create more effects like Instagram. So need different color channel mixers for that
How to create them?

Ref. -- https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects/wiki/Permanent-video-effects

I got only 2 filters

Sepia
colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131

Grayscale
colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3

I need more filters.

```
private void initVideoRecorder(String path) { 
try { 
filter = new F FmpegFrameFilter("colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131", VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight()); 
videoRecorder = FFmpegFrameRecorder.createDefault(path, VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight()); videoRecorder.start(); 
} 
catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
 }
```

Comment: Not an Instagram user so I don't know what effects or filters you want. You should list the effects you want, preferably with examples, and we may be able to give you some commands.